# Problem Running SciKit Learn on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3b+

I have jut bought a Raspberry Pi 4 and I'm having trouble installing SKLearn.

I did pip3 install scikit-learn and from what I could tell it installed fine.

I then tried to run a quick Linear Regression with it and get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "New_File_1.py", line 9, in <module>
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .fixes import np_version
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 384, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 179, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .qhull import *
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm completely stumped. My script works fine on 2 other computers but not the Pi?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Googling the error msg suggests installing `libatlas-base-dev` may help

Comment: That did the trick thanks very much mate

Comment: @Dirk Please make an answer so it can be accepted to close the question.

Comment: This has been answered several times on SO (not raspberry pi SO) e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784520/numpy-import-error-python3-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: @Dirk True, but the SE policy is to allow a question to be answered on every site it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `libatlas3-base` package. This happened because you installed `scikit-learn` with `pip` instead of `apt`. `pip` can install **only** Python modules, so external dependencies are left unsatisfied.

Consider installing software with `apt`, and use `pip` only when the module you need is not available as an `apt` package.